# Как задать переменную окружения в debian?

Tags: java, linux, debian

Задал переменную окружения через `vi /etc/environment`. По команде `echo $var1` значение выводится.
Пытаюсь получить её значение из кода `System.getenv("var1")` - возвращает `null`. ОС Debian. Как задать переменную окружения, чтобы была доступна из кода? Приложение на spring boot деплоится на wildfly.

Comment: надо смотреть, кто запускает wildfly, может ему по-особому надо енв давать

Comment: для wildfly создан пользователь wildfly. запускается вроде как сервис. я в linux слабо разбираюсь. как это посмотреть?

Comment: может systemd или docker (`systemctl --type=service`, `docker ps`); дальше смотреть документацию по ним

Comment: запускаете процесс вы, скорее всего, либо init-скриптом, либо systemd-шным unit-файлом. вот туда и вносите нужные вам правки.

Comment: запускаю какой процесс? wildfly установлен и работает постоянно, я его не трогаю, деплою через ci/cd gtlab-runner он запускает плагины для wldfly, которые деплоят приложение на сервер. docker'а нет, просто виртуалка.

Comment: ci/cd же кто-то настроил

Comment: я и настроил. там ничего сложного нет.

Comment: значит и конфиг у этого плагина есть, и документация (наверное)

Comment: что то   я не понимаю.а при чем тут плагин? мне нужно переменную среды установить.

Comment: Если вы wildfly на сервер руками не ставили, и unit-файл не делали, видимо это сделал плагин

Comment: о, тут ещё как бы случайно ещё и «ci/cd gitlab-runner» затесался. с помощью него процесс-то запускаете (тот, что вам «возвращает `null`»)? значит, с помощью него и рулите переменными окружения.

Comment: gitlab-runner запускает команды shell, в частности скачивает исходники с гитлаба, запускает сборщик maven, который запускает плагин, который деплоит war файл на сервер wildfly.